# Find duplicates with groupby in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I read a csv file using Pandas. Then, I am checking to see if there are any duplicate rows in the data using the code below:

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.read_csv("data.csv", na_values=["", " ", "-"])

print df.shape
>> (71644, 15)

print df.drop_duplicates().shape
>> (31171, 15)
```

I find that there are some duplicate rows, so I want to see which rows appear more than once:

```
data_groups = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist())
size = data_groups.size()
size[size > 1]
```

Doing that I get `Series([], dtype: int64)`.

Futhermore, I can find the duplicate rows doing the following:

```
duplicates = df[(df.duplicated() == True)]

print duplicates.shape
>> (40473, 15)
```

So `df.drop_duplicates()` and `df[(df.duplicated() == True)]` show that there are duplicate rows but `groupby` doesn't.

My data consist of strings, integers, floats and nan.

Have I misunderstood something in the functions I mention above or something else happens ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simply add the `reset_index()` to realign aggregates to a new dataframe.

Additionally, the `size()` function creates an unmarked 0 column which you can use to  filter for duplicate row. Then, just find length of resultant data frame to output a count of duplicates like other functions: `drop_duplicates()`, `duplicated()==True`.

```
data_groups = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist())
size = data_groups.size().reset_index() 
size[size[0] > 1]        # DATAFRAME OF DUPLICATES

len(size[size[0] > 1])   # NUMBER OF DUPLICATES
```

Comment: This looks like an elegant solution to me.