# PANDAS : How can I output duplicate values within a group?

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe has a category and subcategory column, and then a column with strings that sometimes are repeated.

My question is for each category (CAT A) which strings are repeated across subcategories (CAT B)

| CAT A | CAT B | Strings |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | **String1** |
| A1 | B1 | String2 |
| A1 | B1 | String3 |
| A1 | B2 | String4 |
| A1 | B2 | String5 |
| A1 | B2 | **String1** |
| A2 | B1 | String1 |
| A2 | B1 | String2 |
| A2 | B1 | String3 |
| A2 | B2 | String4 |
| A2 | B2 | String5 |
| A2 | B2 | String6 |

The output I am looking for

```
A1
Repeated strings in  B1 and B2
"String1"

---

A2
Repeated strings in  B1 and B2
None
```

I'm confused on how to group this and compare the groups.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find duplicates with groupby in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225631/find-duplicates-with-groupby-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try via `duplicated()` with `keep=False`

```
m=df.duplicated(subset=['CAT A','Strings'],keep=False)
#OR via groupby()+transform()
#m=df.groupby('CAT A')['Strings'].transform(lambda x:x.duplicated(keep=False))
```

Finally:

```
out=df.loc[m]
```

output of `out`:

```
   CAT A    CAT B   Strings
0   A1      B1      String1
5   A1      B2      String1
```

If needed a seperate column:

```
df.loc[m,'duplicated']=df.loc[m,'Strings']
```

output of `out` **:**

```
   CAT A CAT B  Strings duplicated
0     A1    B1  String1    String1
1     A1    B1  String2        NaN
2     A1    B1  String3        NaN
3     A1    B2  String4        NaN
4     A1    B2  String5        NaN
5     A1    B2  String1    String1
6     A2    B1  String1        NaN
7     A2    B1  String2        NaN
8     A2    B1  String3        NaN
9     A2    B2  String4        NaN
10    A2    B2  String5        NaN
11    A2    B2  String6        NaN
```

Comment: Seems a bit of a long way around when you can just set the subset: -> `m = df.duplicated(subset=['CAT A', 'Strings'], keep=False)`